# How to create the shadow bottom borders between ViewGroups?

Tags: android, android-layout

I was trying to find a solution for myself but asking you guys can be more direct way to the answer. Can you please look at the picture below:

[image]

and hint me how can I achieve these beautiful shady borders between viewgroups ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Drawable resource file on drawable folder whit this content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#e1e1e1" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- White Top color -->
<item android:bottom="3px" android:left="0px" android:right="2px" android:top="0px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Now set this drawable file to backgroud view ex:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/yourBackground" />
```

Now if you want you can customize the created drawable resource